# No Media file in my local repository on Source Tree from BitBucket

Tags: css, git, repository, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am working on my website and am using SourceTree to edit my website and commit changes to BitBucket however there are some changes that I need to make in the media/css file but there is no media file in my local repository.

How do I get this onto my repository so I can make these changes using git?

As you can see in the image below of my Repository: I am missing the media file.

[Repository file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w01rJ.jpg)

Comment: A fetch or a pull should bring down changes on remote that aren't in your local repo, no? Or am I misunderstanding the issue?